# How to resolve Multi character constant error while initializing a character array?

Tags: c

I want to initialize an array with the following characters in it:

```
 [, ], {, }, |, \, (, ), *, +, $, ^, ., ?
```

but it is showing "Multi character constant error"..
please tell me what are the better ways to resolve this issue??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: char pass_char_arr[76] = { '[', ']', '(', ')', '\', '^', '$', '.', '|', '?', '*', '+', '{', '}',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 
    'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 
    'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
    'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' } ;

 char rand_gen_arr[254];
 unsigned  char password[8];
 int i, j=0;     I know that special characters cannot be accommodated in single byte..that is why the error

Comment: but i want to store them in an array

Comment: Show your code *in the question*, please.

Comment: Post the _exact_ cut & paste 1) line of code that is giving the error/warning and 2) the error message.  This problem has larger relevance and your contribution is of value.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this... Do Initialize every element as ASCII `char`... In elements `\` should be `\\` ..

```
char a[]={  '[',']','{','}','(',')','\\' };
```

Comment: Can you show your code...? can you show your error?

Comment: I used char *a = "[](){}/^".. I think problem is solved for now.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
char chars[] ={ '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', '\\', '(', ')', '*', '+', '$', '^', '.', '?' };
```

or

```
const char *p ="[]{}|\\()*+$^.?";
```